# Why variable sized arrays cause Wrong Answer on Codechef?

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-length-array

```
int n;cin>>n;
int arr[n]{};
```

I have a small problem ,why is this decleration of array wrong?I have used it on Codechef several times until recently i got a WA!

After this I declared array as,

```
int n;cin>>n;
int arr[1001]{0} ; //max size of input possible
```

I got an AC!

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not supported in C++.

Comment: You might use `std::size_t n; std::cin >> n; std::vector<int> arr(n);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - depends on the problem.   I'd probably define `n` as a `std::size_t`, unless there is potential that a negative of `n` would be input.

Comment: @Peter: changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare an array in c++ of variable length
.But you can create an array of variable length dynamically.

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int*arr = new int[n];
```

Comment: You have then to call `delete[] arr;` at the end.